# passing new object as parameter to another new object in java

Tags: java, object, constructor, instance

i was studying this lecture [Visibility, get/set Methods and Constructors with Greenfoot](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UC3Mx+IT.1.1x+3T2017/courseware/ef2feae2107843679a73b440a27efaeb/c172a23a489a4888b7eebe33c340fedb/?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AUC3Mx%2BIT.1.1x%2B3T2017%2Btype%40sequential%2Bblock%40c172a23a489a4888b7eebe33c340fedb)

as part of Introduction to Java Programming: Starting to Code with Java Course 
am just confused about this lines

```
public void populateWorld(){
    Car car1 = new Car(new String("car1.png"), new String("car2.png"));
    Car car2 = new Car(new String("car3.png"), new String("car4.png"));
    addObject(car1, 50, 50);
    addObject(car2, 50, 550);  

}
```

how did the passed a new object as parameter to the car object without giving it a name ?

thanks in advance 
i will appreciate it also if you mention a good similar explanation to the whole 
lecture classes, objects , parameters , constructors and attributes in java 
Regards .

Comment: Why do you think everything needs a variable name?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran the question doesn't require knowledge about the class `Car`

Comment: Objects don't have names. Variables do. A variable just holds a reference to an object.

Comment: Let use a similar logic, is it possible to do numeric operation with `int i = 5 * 3` or do I need to store `int a = 5; int b = 3; int i = a * b;`. An instance use the same idea. You can use it directly without keeping his reference in a variable

Comment: Yes, @Thomas Böhm I misread the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's nothing wrong with this code.

When you call a constructor or a method with params, all what you should do is to pass those `parameters` with the right `types`, **it doesn't matter whether they are variables or new instances**, they just need to be **valid** `objects` with respective **expected types**.

So here:

```
Car car1 = new Car(new String("car1.png"), new String("car2.png"));
```

The `Car` constructor expects two `String` as parameters, and you supplied two strings, this code is equivalent to:

```
Car car1 = new Car("car1.png", "car2.png");
```

Because `new String("")` returns a `String` so the constructor call is fine here because parameters types are respected.

And it's the same thing when you called `addObject(car1, 50, 50);`, you don't need variables for `50` values.

Answer (score 0):

You not need a name for the car object.

This creates an object

```
new String("car1.png");
```

The Object exists and can be passed to the Constructor.

This creates and pointer on a new object

```
Car nameOfCar = new Car("car55.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let use a simpler example first using some numeric operation.

What code is correct :

```
int i = 5 * 3;
```

or

```
int a = 5; 
int b = 3; 
int i = a * b;
```

Both are correct. We don't need to store a value in a variable to use it.

An instance is the same. You can use it directly without keeping its reference in a variable.

```
String s = new Object().toString();
```

or

```
Object o = new Object();
String s = o.toString();
```

The difference in my case is that in the first example, after that statetement, the instance resulting of `new Object()` can't be reached and will be illegible to the garbage collector.

Comment: @Mohamed You can't accept all answers ;) you can upvote all but only accept the one that fit the most. (Just FYI)